# Preserve coherence while shuffling queues in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have 3 queues, one is a FileReader supplied by a string_input_producer, two are slice_input_producers fed by a vector of int32 and a matrix of int32 respectively. They are all ordered such that, when read in sequence, they provide an image, question, and answer that forms one example.

What I want to do is shuffle them, while preserving the relations between them.

I've tried using shuffle_batch, but this does not preserve the relations - making it useless.

My current code (the relevant bits):

```
def load_images(self,images,q_name):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(images,shuffle=False,name=q_name)
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    imagedata = tf.image.decode_png(value)
    imagedata = tf.cast(tf.image.resize_images(imagedata,[224,224],tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR),tf.float32)
    imagedata = tf.div(imagedata,tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(imagedata)))
    imagedata.set_shape([224,224,3])
    return key,imagedata

keys[testfile],imagedata[testfile] = self.load_images(imagefiles[testfile],'test')
keys[trainfile],imagedata[trainfile] = self.load_images(imagefiles[trainfile],'train')

s_train_answer_batch,s_train_question_batch,s_train_image_batch = tf.train.batch([tf.train.slice_input_producer([answers[trainfile]],shuffle=False)[0],tf.train.slice_input_producer([questions[trainfile]],shuffle=False)[0],imagedata[trainfile]],batch_size=batch_size,capacity=batch_size*2,enqueue_many=False)

feed_dict = {self.x_image:s_train_image_batch.eval(), self.x_question: s_train_question_batch.eval(), self.y_:s_train_answer_batch.eval(),self.keep_prob:keep_prob}

_,ce, summary, image_summary, accuracy= sess.run([self.train_step,self.cross_entropy, self.summary_op, self.image_summary_op, self.accuracy],feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

So, to be absolutely clear: if the image, question, and answer matrices where just vectors of the numbers one to ten, I'd want the feed dictionary to look like:

```
q:[4,1,8,2,3,9,6,5,7],a:[4,1,8,2,3,9,6,5,7],i:[4,1,8,2,3,9,6,5,7]
```

but currently they'd look like:

```
q:[4,1,8,2,3,9,6,5,7],a:[7,3,1,5,6,2,4,9,8],i:[9,8,3,5,4,6,7,1,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Don't use .eval() to get the output, call sess.run([image_batch,question_batch,answer_batch]). This preserves ordering and does the shuffling. I have no idea why.

Comment: There should be a better way to do this. You shouldn't have to sess.run() to get your examples. And using a feed_dict defeats the purpose of the reader in addition to being less efficient, since you're piping things out of the reader then into the feed dict, adding more nodes to the graph and copying data multiple times. Did you try having the three separate readers return one image/question/answer, and call `tf.train.shuffle_batch([image,question,answer])`? That function won't be where the reordering happens, it should be coming from earlier.

Comment: I think perhaps I've miscomunicated what I did. To be clear, my code now looks like:
     `b_image,_question,b_answer = sess.run(s_train_answer_batch,s_train_question_batch,s_train_image_batch)`
    `feed_dict  = {self.x_image:b_image, self.x_question: b_question, self.y_:b_answe,self.keep_prob:keep_prob}`

Comment: No that made sense, but it's inefficient. You should either use a feed_dict or reader pipeline, not both. You'll waste time copying data out of the batch function (when calling sess.run) and into the feed_dict for each batch. The batch function provides the input tensors that go into the graph in place of the feed_dict. Also try using `a_q = tf.train.slice_input_producer([answers[trainfile], questions[trainfile]], shuffle=False)`. Answer a_q[0] and question a_q[1] should be in correct order if tensors `answers[trainfile]` and `questions[trainfile]` are also in order with each other.

Comment: Oh I see! Yeah, I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use a single queue, like `tf.train.range_input_producer` with `shuffle`, to extract an integer used to access the different data?

In other words, you use a single queue to extract an integer that you use to index all your three data structures.

Comment: I can't load the images into memory and access them as an array because there are too many and they're too large. I could potentially hold off loading the images until the last minute and index the string array instead, but that would be significantly slower because I couldn't pre-load a batch first.